# Non-existent function header

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-reference

The program control doesn't enter the function when I pass a pointer to a built-in character array into the function, whose prototype is "void f(int, char *)".
In the function, I am trying to increment the position to which the pointer points inside the array using pointer arithmetic, and the value at that address.
What can be the possible reasons for the control to ignore the function? There are no compilation or logical errors in my program.

Comment: You likely didn't build with symbols so there is nothing to step into. Did you make sure there is a `.pdb` file (for Visual Studio) created for that library? What is your build environment (OS, IDE, compiler, etc)?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the function is entered normally, but that it appears to you as though it weren't because you don't see the pointer change as you expect. The reason you don't see the pointer change is that you are not passing the pointer by reference. Change the function signature to

```
void f(int num, char *&ptr)
```

then changes to the pointer inside the function will be visible outside -- otherwise they are applied to a copy of the pointer that exists only for the duration of the function call.